# password_verify shows invalid password in function

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, password-hash

I am trying to work with `passrord_hash()` and `password_verify()`. The below code works perfect.

```
$timeTarget = 0.2; 
$pass = "";
$cost = 9;
do {
$cost++;
$start = microtime(true);
$pass = password_hash("qwerty", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
    $end = microtime(true);
} while (($end - $start) < $timeTarget);

echo "Appropriate Cost Found: " . $cost . "\n";
echo $pass;


$hash = $pass;

if (password_verify('qwerty', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

but when I convert it to function, it shows invalid password. I echoed the passing values in the functions. It shows the right value. But the result turns wrong. I can't understand what is wrong with the code

```
$str = "qwerty";

$enc = encrypt($str);

verify_string($str, $enc);



function encrypt($pass){
$timeTarget = 0.2; 
$cost = 9;
do {
    $cost++;
    $start = microtime(true);
    $pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
    $end = microtime(true);
} while (($end - $start) < $timeTarget);


echo $pass."<br />";
return $pass;
}

function verify_string($str, $enc){
echo $str." :  ".$enc."<br />";

if (password_verify($str, $enc)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!<br />';
}
    else {
    echo 'Invalid password.<br />';
}
}
```

Please help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this loop?

Comment: i got this code from the tutorial "http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php" this is for increase the cost and by doing that increase the hashing security

Comment: @sectus : sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please explain?

Comment: The puprose of this code is to get `Cost`. But you are trying to use it as encrypt function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 . Loop uses const value of password

```
$pass = password_hash("qwerty", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
```

2 . Loop uses variable $pass and and puts varialbe to $pass. On the second circle variable $pass contains hash, but not the password.

```
$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => $cost]);
```

Comment: this works fine. But i get this code from php tutorial .This loop will set a cost based on the server capacity.

Comment: Wow...now its worked. I copied $pass to another variable and put that in function. Thnak you very much

Comment: @Arun , Do not use this code. Just use `password_hash`.

Comment: @Arun . To improve your security you need set `Cost` as higher as possible. To findout cost you need to run code from example only once on target server. Then use results in settings of your app.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will do as you said .. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54094/discussion-between-arun-and-sectus).